# Compile C++/C for android devices on a linux platform

Tags: android, c++, c, ubuntu, cross-compiling

I am currently running the latest version of Ubuntu, and would like to compile some C++ and C into an executable that Android is capable of running. I've looked, but can't seem to find any compilers I can install in order to cross compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile an existing C program for Android using NDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197912/how-do-i-compile-an-existing-c-program-for-android-using-ndk)

Comment: This application is entirely C/C++, there is not java component

Comment: You still need to use the Android NDK, Also you should probably 'start' with a java activity (just for early sanity check that your NDK is working properly, then you can remove the Java Activity and go pure C/C++)